# Silly me & Van der Waerden conjecture

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, permanent

So I walked into this very innocent-looking combinatorics problem,
and quite soon I ended up with the problem to prove that any doubly stochastic $n \times n$ matrix has a non-zero permanent.

Now clearly, this follows from the Van der Waerden conjecture (which is now a theorem), which give a lower (positive) bound for the permanent..

However, in my case, it feels like overkill to reference this theorem, so I wonder if there is some elementary argument that shows that the permanent of a doubly stochastic matrix is positive. (Although, the lower bound mentioned above converges to 0, as the matrix size grows, so it must be non-trivial...).

Or, is proving that the permanent is non-zero "as hard as" proving the lower bound?

Comment: The title sounds a bit misleading...

Comment: @FelixGoldberg: Ok fixed.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a tag. Hope u don't mind.

Comment: *"So I walked into this very innocent-looking combinatorics problem"* Sure, sure, that's what they all say buddy.  Now face forward towards the camera, please...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's known (again using Hall's theorem, or using convex analysis) that the doubly stochastic matrices are a convex combination of the permutation matrices (these are the extreme points of the collection of doubly stochastic matrices). Accordingly each doubly stochastic matrix is a finite positive linear combination of permutation matrices. Then that the permanent is non-zero is immediate.

Comment: Ah, this sounds very familiar! Thanks! This has its own theorem, the Birkhoff–von Neumann theorem, I realized.

Comment: Moreover this argument gives a (very bad, but very elementary) lower bound on the permanent: there are at most $n!$ terms in the sum describing a doubly stochastic matrix as a convex combination of permutation matrices, so at least one such term has coefficient at least $\frac{1}{n!}$, and hence there is a contribution to the permanent of size at least $\frac{1}{(n!)^n}$. (This is addressing the "lower bound... converges to $0$... so it must be nontrivial" part of the OP.)

Comment: So van der Waerden's conjecture is an elaborate generalization of Hall's marriage theorem. Nice!

Comment: Wait! I can do "even better" than $1/(n!)^n$! If you put weight $\epsilon_i$ on permutation $\sigma_i$ and ignore cross terms, then you get a lower bound of $\sum_{i=1}^{n!}\epsilon_i^{n}$. The minimum of this occurs when all the $\epsilon_i$ are $1/n!$ so we have the massive improvement to $1/(n!)^{n-1}$.

Comment: Any $n\times n$ doubly stochastic matrix is a positive linear combination of no more than $n^2-2n+2$ permutation matrices.

Comment: @Gerry: Do you have a reference for this? Or is there a very simple proof?

Comment: See my paper with David Leep, Marriage, Magic, and Solitaire, Amer Math Monthly,  Vol. 106, No. 5, May, 1999, pages 419-429 (but especially page 423), or the paper we cribbed it from, Marcus and Ree, Diagonals of doubly stochastic matrices, Quart J Math 10 (1959) 295-302.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas: The $n^2-2n+2$ follows immediately from Carathéodory's theorem (if $X$ is a subset of an $m$-dimensional linear variety in $R^d$, then any point in the convex hull of $X$ can be expressed as a convex combination of at most $d+1$ points of $X$). I guess it is the "positive" part that sets apart Gerry's statement.

Answer (score 17):

Let me cite here a famous result that is equivalent to Hall's theorem, and from which the positivity of the permanent of a DS matrix follows.

> **Theorem** ([Frobenius-König](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Frobenius-KoenigTheorem.html)). The permanent of an $n\times n$ nonnegative matrix $A$ is zero *if and only if* $A$ has an $r\times s$ zero submatrix with $r+s=n+1$.

From this theorem a brief argument shows that for a DS matrix $A$, we must have $\text{per}\ A > 0$.

Comment: @Tony: the 0,1 condition is not needed, so I removed it. Please see, e.g., Thm. 2.2 here: http://books.google.com/books?id=gnT2LCvciqUC&lpg=PA31&ots=mD7aDstn18&dq=frobenius%20koening%20theorem&pg=PA31#v=onepage&q=frobenius%20koening%20theorem&f=false

Comment: Nice!  Sorry, I did not know that.  You should restore the non-negativity condition though.

Comment: In fact, when Van der Waerden [originally posed his question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/343596), he noted that the positivity follows from König's theorem.

Answer (score 10):

The ($n \times n$) matrix represents a bipartite graph (with $2n$ vertices) which is basically its zero-nonzero pattern. If you can show the graph has a perfect matching (by Hall's theorem or some other way) you're done.

Comment: Oh, let me clarify my question a bit..