# Van der Waerden conjecture and Alexandrov-Fenchel inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-geometry, permanent

The [Van der Waerden conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_(mathematics)#Van_der_Waerden%27s_conjecture) is a lower estimate of the permanent of a doubly stochastic matrix. In this article in Wikipedia it is stated that Egorychev's proof uses the Alexandrov-Fenchel inequality for mixed volumes of convex bodies. Here is a [link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/000187088190044X) to the proof (which is very short). Egorychev himself mentioned the latter inequality but in a less direct way I think.

**Where exactly the Alexandrov-Fenchel inequality is used in the proof?**

I think what is actually used is Alexandrov's inequality for mixed discriminants of symmetric matrices which Alexandrov invented for one of his proofs of the Alexandrov-Fenchel inequality. But the former inequality is easier than and different from the latter.

Comment: the link to the proof appears to be incorrect.

Comment: I think you yourself answered your question.

Comment: @Mark: Correcred.

Answer (score 2):

Egorychev’s proof of van der Waerden’s conjecture is dicussed by Martinez in [Notes on the proof of the van der Waerden permanent conjecture](https://dr.lib.iastate.edu/server/api/core/bitstreams/3bd53ae6-a7ba-459e-bd35-7781efd00145/content) (page 23). The Aleksandrov (1938) inequality needed is:

[image]

<sub>Historical note: This MO [post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/343593/11260) argues that Van de Waerden did not actually formulate the conjecture that has his name.</sub>

Comment: I don't see here an answer to the question "**Where exactly** the **Alexandrov-Fenchel inequality** is used in [**Egorychev's**]proof?" The answer is apparently "nowhere".